# Outlook Add-In AppDomain for the current tenant

Tags: office365, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

How can you set an appdomain in the manifest.xml for the current sharepoint online/onedrive (https://xxx.sharepoint.com) so that you can actually open links to ie onedrive from an outlook add-in? Is there a certain placeholder for this like for instance: http://sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the external domains that your add-in would access. for example for SharePoint online instance, you can use:

https://MyCompanyTenantName.sharepoint.com

Same applies to external apis/endpoints, for example:

https://*.companyapi.com

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really. In a multitenant app you don't really know what domains the customer has set in advance.

Comment: It depends in your case, if it is a multi tenant app and you still load certain data from a specific domain, you still need to authorize this domain to be accessible to your app.